# ASP.NET Core WebSocket failed during handshake

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, websocket

I'm trying to use ASP.NET Core WebSocket, but got an error like this when `new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5702");` in JavaScript:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5702/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

My Configure method in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
     app.UseDefaultFiles();

     app.UseStaticFiles();

     app.UseWebSockets();
     app.UseWebSocketHandler();
}
```

My `Middlewares\WebSocketMiddleware.cs`:
[WebSocketMiddleware.cs](http://pastebin.com/GP6KJNaL)

Does anyone know?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour you are experiencing is because some other middleware (UseStaticFiles) is returning a 200 OK code to your websocket client.

To avoid this, make sure to place your WebSocket middleware **before** UseStaticFiles(). Personally, I'd put it at the top, like so:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        //first handle any websocket requests
        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseWebSocketHandler();

        //now handle other requests (default, static files, mvc actions, ...)
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        //app.UseMvc(...);
    }
```